# Use angular controller in dynamically loaded html

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have following code

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('myModule', ['schemaForm', 'base64', 'ngRoute']);
```

taskController.js

```
app.controller('TaskController', function($scope, AuthService, $http, $base64, $location) {
    $scope.fetchFormKey = function() {
        $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + AuthService.auth;
        $http.get(restServerURL + '/task/' + $scope.taskId + '/form').
        success(function(data) {
            $scope.formKey = "./partials/itpTrainingCreation/" + data.key + ".html";
        });
    }

}
```

task.html

```
<h2>Generated form</h2>
<div ng-controller="TaskController" ng-init="fetchFormKey()">
    <div ng-include src="formKey"></div>
</div>
```

In dynamically loaded file (loaded by ng-include) i want to define angular controller which will be used by this file.

dynamic.html (example)

```
<script>
angular.module('myModule').controller('DymanicController', function($scope, AuthService, $http, $base64, $location) {
 $scope.exampleValue="myCustomValue";
});
</script>
<div ng-controller="DymanicController">
    {{exampleValue}}
</div>
```

Unfortunately i get following error:
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.5/ng/areq?p0=DymanicController&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined

How can I change my code to fix this problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15250644/loading-an-angularjs-controller-dynamically

Answer (score 2):

I assume your dynamic contents have some template. I think you should take look at [script](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/script) in angularjs

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="/tpl.html">
  Content of the template.
</script>
```

and use ui-routing to add your dynamic content, assign controller there in router.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna load a module on the fly I recommend ocLazyload. That worked pretty well in one side project of mine.

```
myApp.controller("MyCtrl", function($ocLazyLoad) {
  $ocLazyLoad.load('testModule.js');
});
```

works well with routers.

Answer (score 0):

I found similar question [how to include javascript file specific to each view angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12436679/how-to-include-javascript-file-specific-to-each-view-angularjs)

```
    You can't. Angular does not load javascript parts from a template.
    What you should do is to include them in your main application anyway.
    All of the controllers should be loaded while the main app is initiating.
```

Could someone confirm this thesis?